# From a C#/.NET assembly, how do I load a C++/CLR DLL which loads an unmanaged DLL?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a Visual Studio 2017 solution with the following projects:

```
CppClrQuestion             -- Solution
    CUnamagedLib           -- C++ Unmanaged Windows DLL
        CUnmanagedLib.cpp
        CUnmanagedLib.h
    ClrManagedLib          -- C++/CLR DLL Project
        ClrManagedLib.cpp
        ClrManagedLib.h
    CSharpDotNetConsoleApp -- C#/.NET
        Program.cs
```

`CSharpDotNetConsoleApp` has a project reference to `ClrManagedLib` and `ClrManagedLib` has a project reference to `CUnamagedLib`.

Everything compiles OK. However, when I run the C# application I get this exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'CppClrLib2.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.'
```

If I change `ClrManagedLib` so that it doesn't call anything in `CUnamagedLib`, it runs OK.

How do I set up a solution where I have a C# app which references a managed C++/CLR lib which then references an unmanaged C++ lib?

For reference, here are the source file contents:

### CUnmanagedLib.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
__declspec(dllexport) int GetNumUnmanaged(void) {
    return 5;
}
```

### CUnmanagedLib.h

```
#pragma once
__declspec(dllimport) int GetNumUnmanaged(void);
```

### ClrManagedLib.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "..\CUnamangedLib\CUnmanagedLib.h"
#include "ClrManagedLib.h"

int ClrManagedLib::Class1::GetNum() {
    return GetNumUnmanaged(); 
}
```

### ClrManagedLib.h

```
#pragma once
using namespace System;
namespace ClrManagedLib {
    public ref class Class1
    {
    public:
        int GetNum();
    };
}
```

### Program.cs

```
namespace CSharpDotNetConsoleApp {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var managedObj = new ClrManagedLib.Class1();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is said code compiled to a DLL and *placed* in the appropriate library/output path? The source is only relevant to compilation, not loading: ie. _where_ is CppClrLib2.dll?

Comment: CppClrLib2.dll is in the default location when you create these projects from scratch: `Solution Dir/Debug`. `CUnmanaged.dll` is also in this location. Interestingly enough, I don't run into this problem if a C++/CLR console app uses CppClrLib2.dll instead of a C#/.NET console app.

Answer (score 0):

Windows will identify the required unmanaged DLL, but it only looks in a few places for it.  Make sure you have a copy there.  In the old days, everyone piled everything in the Windows\System32 subfolder.  Don't do that.
Details:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/7d83bc18.aspx
More details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order

Comment: This tells me where the default search paths are. However, these projects, by default, should be using implicit linking--so why does the C# app find the managed library on its own, but not when that library calls functions in an unmanaged library in the same location. I can put my `Solution Dir/Debug` path in my PATH variable and then everything works. However, that seems far from ideal development practice.

Comment: You can either add a post-build command to copy the unmanaged DLL to the proper locations, or add the DLL to your project, set the Build Action to none and tell VS to copy it to the output directory.  I find it is often less trouble to use the post-build command mechanism.

Comment: I used the post-build action. This works. I don't know why VS insists on `Solution Dir\Debug` for C++ code and `Solution Dir\Project Dir\Debug` for C#/.NET code. It seems to make things a lot more complicated. Would you mind adding your comment about post-build actions to your answer? You might also mention that "Enable native code debugging" needs to be checked in the C#/.NET application if you want to be able to step into the unmanaged library.